# Why isn't encrypted DNS more widely adopted?

Tags: encryption, dns

Considering recent (and arguably successful, if slow because of their large scale) efforts to make encrypted HTTP communication ubiquitous using SSL/TLS via such CAs as Let's Encrypt, and the presence of the DNSCrypt protocol, why aren't clients and servers offering encrypted DNS more common?

In most cases, it seems like DNSCrypt requires the installation of additional software on the client, which can then access a select few servers (or even just proxies) running DNSCrypt on their ends. Meanwhile, many of the large, commonly-used DNS providers don't actually allow for DNSCrypt connections.

Comment: Similar: why is IPv6 adoption so slow, why is DNSec adoption slow, why people don't patch fast enough even though there are patches out there, why people still use Windows XP... . All of this is probably caused by limited resources and too much other important things. So compared to all the other unfixed issues: why should DNS providers and end users consider encrypted DNS  more important than the other problems? What do they gain and how much does it cost to roll it out? And are there cheaper alternatives which cover the main problems relevant for the end user too?